# Can we get the Instagram posts by hashtag?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to set up an instagram hashtag posts block for my site by js.

I know I need to use the [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api) API and get a Access Token to send the request. But it expires after 1 hour and I don't want to have to manually refresh it. Does anyone know a good, preferably free, way of doing this automatically or get the Long-Lived Access Token for this case?

Any ideas or links would be really helpful, thanks!

A solution or a video tutorial

Answer (score 0):

you can use this endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&fb_exchange_token={your_short_time_access_token}
```

it returns a long live token. (It expires after 60 days)

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But this access token can't use to get the Instagram posts by hashtag